# How to select all inputs that autogenerate on a form and pick the last one?

Tags: jquery, field

I have a form into which the user can add more fields to fill by clicking on the "add" anchor (#addLink). However I also have a table with possible data and the purpose of it is so that if the user adds a new row of fields he can click then the row on the table that fits the most and the fields fill themselves. I can't seem to be able to do this though because I can't get a function that checks how many fields are and just fills the last one (I have to know how many there are to fill the last one and not replace everything else). The fields were created by another programmer and I don't have access to that code. He doesn't give me id's or classes just names which are of the form "links[n][url]" (where n = a number and the word url literally).

So far I had:

```
$('#addLink').click(function(){
        //links[n][url]
        var $inputs = $('#links :input'); //#links is a div that contains the fields
        var names = {};

        $inputs.each(function(index){
            alert(index + ' : ' + $(this).attr('id'));
            ids[$(this).attr('name')];
        });
    });
```

but it just alerts (0 : ); nothing else. What am I missing?

Comment: you try to read the id attribute which is not set (that is what you say in the text above) I think you need the name attribute

Comment: I already tried it only when after the click happens not even there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#addLink').click(function(){

    var inputs = $('#links:input:last'); //#links is a div that contains the fields
    var names = {};


        alert(inputs.index() + ' : ' + $(inputs).attr('id'));


});
```

Are you just trying to select the last one? :inputs:last

Answer (score 0):

Why you use #links if it the name of field, you might use $("input[name^='links']"); if the fields name start by links.

Regards,

Comment: I still get the 0 : and I can't really make it a fiddle because this uses php =/